# Disabling button is not working for angular4 validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular4-forms

I have a submit button in my form, i am trying to disable it until all the text-boxes are filled. Its not working after page is refreshed or loaded for the first time in browser. If i perform any other operation in the same page and then open this add detail pop up it is disabled. Help will be much appreciated.

component

```
form: FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
}
createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        addrs: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

HTML file

```
<div id="details">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addDetails()" name="form" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Please Enter Name"
                formControlName="name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="addrs">Address</label><input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="addrs"
                placeholder="Please Enter Address" formControlName="addrs" >

        <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid || loading"
            class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="loading" class="alert alert-success box-msg" role="alert">
            <strong>Added Successfully</strong>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please dont tag angular questions with angularjs, or with extra non-relevant tags ie: `angular4-httpclient`

Comment: what is **loading** ?

Comment: That's a Boolean i have called in addDetails function, when its true it shows success msg.

Comment: `formControlName="Name"` should be `formControlName="name"`, no?

Comment: youre missing a quote (in the question atleast): `(ngSubmit)="addDetails(); name="form"` should be `(ngSubmit)="addDetails();" name="form"`

Comment: Can you reproduce the error here in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nlgws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), I don't see any issues

Comment: why do you have a blank `ngModel`?

Comment: while posting here i missed. In my original code its fine.

Comment: @Janny: Did you try to give the input-fields the `required` attribute once more in the view. I see that you already assign `Validators.required` in the `FormBuilder`, but just give it a try also in the view and keep both... I had once similar issue. And I would also try to invoke the function on the button: `(click)="addDetails()"` not on the form-tag.

Comment: i tried that too. But its not working.

Comment: @Janny: If I understand what you try to reach, then the button will disabled if inputs are invalid or  `loading` is `true`. If you remove `loading` from: `[disabled]="form.invalid || loading"` what happens then? remove `loading` it and keep just `[disabled]="form.invalid"` to localize the exact issue. And from your answer above the `loading` will be set to `true` of `false` just after invoking the function `addDetails()`.

Comment: i have tried that too, its not working. ts not working after page is refreshed or loaded for the first time in browser. If i perform any other operation in the same page and then open this add detail pop up it is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using no validate in form tag?
if no validate is mention in the form ,then the form will not get validated.it will simply execute accept whatever you enter inside the form.try and execute without novalidate ang ngmodel in input tag.it will work

Comment: novalidate is from preventing the browser side default validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.status === 'INVALID' || loading"
        class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

That should consider both options, loading and the invalid form.